# How to determine if this filter is stable

Tags: filter, stable

Hi I have a filter which has the following transfer function:

H(z) = (z^2 + 0.04)/(z^2 + 3.24) for which i need to determine whether this is stable or not. I'm not sure how to attempt this, but I'm thinking it has something to do with the poles and zero's (just taking a guess here).

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: What do you know about stability ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zeroes of H don't play any role in stability.

For the filter to be stable, you have to ensure that all **poles** of H are inside the unit circle, i.e. their modulus (distance of the pole from the origin of the Z-plane) is less than one.

In your case the poles are the zeroes of the polynomial at denominator, i.e the roots of the equation \$z^2 + 3.24 = 0\$. Solve this and verify whether its roots \$z_k\$ are such that

\$\left| z_k \right| < 1 \quad \forall k\$.

Comment: The roots are: z = +- 1.8j and |z| = 1.8 which is clearly greater than 1 thus we can conclude the filter isnt stable.

Thanks a lot for your help man, really appreciate it!